# Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments in IRepository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have a problem in my code below mentioned.It askes me the 1 argument.
IRepository

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    List GetAll(); // Error shows me here then i change this to List<User> GetAll(); but still getting the error.
}
```

Repository

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private IDbConnection _db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    public List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return this._db.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM Users").ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<User>` should be in both: interface and implementation

Comment: i use this example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874219/Use-Dapper-NET-ORM-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: OHHHHHHHHH NOOOO!! `GetAll` (very ugly!) and also you retrieve all users in memory!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: @TechGuy, seems like in article problem with markup in sample, so you should not use it as is. Also seems c# not have non generic version for `List` class

Answer (score 2):

You should try with:

```
public interface IUserRepository<T>
{
    List<T> GetAll(); 
}
```

And then:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository<User>
{
    private IDbConnection _db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    public List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return this._db.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM Users").ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: it also not success.i use this example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874219/Use-Dapper-NET-ORM-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: @TechGuy in the sample you provided is not clear exactly which type of `List` is the one returned by `GetAll` interface